# How to preserve mahapps metro styling when adding custom trigger?

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I had a button that was styled in the default metro style.  However when I added a trigger to the button, the style is overridden.  How to preserve the original mahapps metro styling when adding your own style and triggers?

```
    <Button x:Name="startButton" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,20,26" Width="75" Click="startButton_Click" Height="67" Grid.Column="1">
        <!--<Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>-->
    </Button>
```

This is how the button looked originally

[image: Before]

This is how it looks after I added the trigger

[image: After]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the "BasedOn" property of your style to the one mahapps.metro is providing as default:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroButton}">
```

The documentation doesn't say the default static resource, but it's OpenSource so easy to track it down in the source code for the Controls.xaml you import to load the default styles in your app.xaml (or top of window etc):

https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/tree/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/Styles

A search for TargetType="Button" finds our default style (without a key):

Which is even also based on the base style, `MahApps.Metro.Styles.MetroButton`.

Comment: Thank you, how do I find the correct static resource?

Comment: I was hoping you'd know (hence my placeholder!). It's always a pain to find out! Added some more describing how I usually do it.

Comment: I suppose there is no way to view the resource dictionaries from within Visual studio?

Comment: I've only ever had intelisense show up resources I've defined. There might be a way, I haven't looked into it.

Comment: I tested it and it worked thank you, but I used this `BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroButton}"` without the 'MahApps.Metro.Styles.'

Comment: This doesn't appear to work anymore. At least, I couldn't find a reference to MetroButton in the repository as of 5/21/2021.

Oops, my bad! I'm using the MaterialDesign add-on so the button reference I wanted is BasedOn="{Static Resource MaterialDesignRaisedButton}"

Comment: I use BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.Button}" this seems to work.